# How do we start a user task in activiti?

Tags: jsf, activiti

I tried to start a task in my jsf page as follows:

```
<f:metadata>

    <!--             start working on the usertask and starting a conversation  -->
    <f:event type="preRenderView"
        listener="#{businessProcess.startTask('userTask', true)}" />
</f:metadata>
```

But i get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot resume task with id 'userTask', no such task.
```

Any suggestions to solve my problem?

Comment: Make sure the 'userTask' exists... (this is not a JSF issue, although you do it from jsf. Most likely creating some unitTest like class would make it fail to

Comment: Are you sure you are starting a task? The error says "resume".

Comment: Yes i am starting a task and the task exists. I checked the method startTask and the exception is thrown when the task is null

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this:

```
<f:viewParam name="userTask" />
```

and you must delete the apostrophe 'userTask' put it like this 
   businessProcess.startTask(userTask,true)

You can try  this:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="userTask" />
    <!--start working on the usertask and starting a conversation-->
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#
            {businessProcess.startTask(userTask,true)}"  ></f:event>
</f:metadata>
```